# Server does not support secure connections asp.net

Tags: asp.net, security, connection

I will repeat already asked question in the hope to get solution.
In my computer the following function works fine.

```
void sendEmail(string mailto, string subject, string body)
        {
            try
            {
                mydataTableAdapter mta = new mydataTableAdapter();
                string email = mta.GetData().Rows[0]["email"].ToString();
                string password = mta.GetData().Rows[0]["password"].ToString();
                MailMessage objMail = new MailMessage(email, mailto, subject, body);
                NetworkCredential objNC = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
                SmtpClient objsmtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru",25);
                objsmtp.EnableSsl = true;
                objsmtp.Credentials = objNC;
                objsmtp.Send(objMail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Response.Write(ex.Message); }
        }
```

But when I run this project in web server, the following error occured: **Server does not support secure connections** and sending email fails.

I tried make:

```
EnableSsl = false

objsmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

but, none of these solves the problem

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1091403.aspx).

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496566/error-server-does-not-support-secure-connections

Answer (score 0):

First try out sending mail via GMAIL configuration, if it goes then the reason is due to restrictions on my smtp server.

Contact your network admin and ask for assistance.

In your case it could also be due to host and port issues.